# Nuclear Interaction Stopping Power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

Hello again question board.
I'm in need of some help with my b) question for homework I have. Following question is verbatim:

"How thick should a wall of shielding iron be to absorb a 10 GeV/c pion beam. Use the PDG table and the lecture notes to find the necessary parameters. a) Compute the thickness if the ionization loss would be the only source of energy loss. (Hint: make a simple model or use plots from the lecture.) b) The pion may lose energy also via nuclear interaction. The nuclear interaction length is $\text{132.1 g/cm}^2$. Compute the thickness for pure nuclear interaction effects. (Use an intensity reduction of $10^9$.)"

I have been struggling with this assignment for the past few days, and for the life of me I can't find any information (aside from it being a real thing, and that the nuclear interaction stopping power being far lower than the ionization stopping power) on how exactly to answer the question, meaning, I can't find any sort of formula to use. Any hints or tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what the PDG is?

Comment: I've ordered the book from CERN, but I won't get it before October sadly - and I've only [found](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf) which to the best of my knowledge does not contain what I need, or maybe it does, but I thiiiink it only explains electronic energy loss - but perhaps I've missed something during my reads. One do get blind for what you're looking for eventually.

Comment: You've go the right resources. That chapter is packed full of more information than you will appreciate at first. In any case, the problem statement tells you everything that you need to know beyond looking up the mass and charge of the pion and the bit you've found. Typically the figures are used unless you need high precision results.

Comment: I'm guessing I'm missing something very basic then, because I don't really know what "intensity reduction of $ 10^9 $" means, aside from well -- reducing the intensity -- but the only formula that I've found, that might be useful, is: $$ I=I_o e^(\frac{x}{\lambda}) $$ but then I have the issue that I want I=0, which makes me end up with ln(0), which isn't very helpful.

Comment: All of the PDG is online, as far as I know. I looked into the chapter of interaction of charged particles with matter, and it seems to me, that what you need for your homework is there.

Comment: I honestly can't see anything related to what I need (aside from it being mentioned under figure 32.2), I'm fairly certain I've managed to do a) using Bethe-Bloch, but I'm honestly clueless when it comes to b). But since it's there somewhere...guess I just gotta re-read it until I figure it out.

Comment: Intensity reduction of $10^9$ means that if you can express your intensity as a function of thickness as $e^{-x/\lambda}$, then that expression needs to become $10^{-9}$ (and not, as you thought, zero). If you have two processes which each give a certain intensity at distance $x$, you multiply their intensities (=probability of transmission) to get their combined result. That should help you a bit?...

Comment: I'm insanely tired, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "If you have two processes which each give a certain intensity at distance x, you multiply their intensities (=probability of transmission) to get their combined result.", will have to look it over again after I'm rested - but the rest makes life a lot easier for me - even though I'm not quite sure if you mean that I should have $I=10^{-9}$ or $ln(\frac{I}{I_0})=10^{-9}$, but I'll do some fiddling around in the morning to try to figure out which makes more sense! Thank you ever so much.

Comment: He means the former. The intensity of the radiation is to be reduced by a factor of $10^p$ from it's starting value. You're almost there.